# How to mutate a new variable in R dyplyr that is based on criteria from 2 columns?

Tags: r

I have a dataset which looks like this:

```
Recipient  ID
(chr)       (chr)  
Smith       C
Wells       S
Wells       S
Jones       S
Jones       N
Wu          C
Wu          N
Wu          S
```

I want to mutate a new variable, which is either "Unique" or "Multiple", based on if Recipient appears once (Unique), Recipient appears more than once but has the same ID for each occurence (Unique), Recipient appears more than once AND has 1 or more IDs (Multiple). I've tried to use:

```
df %>%
 group_by(Recipient, ID) %>%
 mutuate(Freq = case_when(
                str_count(Recipient) == 1 & str_count(ID) == 1 ~ "Unique",
                str_count(Recipient) > 2 & str_count(ID) == 1 ~ "Unique",
                str_count(Recipient) > 2 & str_count(ID) > 1 ~ "Multiple"))
```

When I did this, all the values were multiple:

```
Recipient  ID     Freq
(chr)      (chr)  (chr)
Smith       C     Multiple (should be Unique)
Wells       S     Multiple (should be Unique)
Wells       S     Multiple (should be Unique)
Jones       S     Multiple
Jones       N     Multiple
Wu          C     Multiple
Wu          N     Multiple
Wu          S     Multiple
```

I've tried multiple times, but can't crack it. Can anyone help to solve this, or recommend an easier way to code this? Thanks!

Comment: I think your output is wrong. For example `wu + C` only appears once but you have multiple...?

Comment: Sorry just to clarify: criteria for "Unique" should be Recipient appears once, or Recipient appears more than once, but has the same ID at each row. Multiple criteria should be Recipient appears more than once and has a different ID in at least 1 row. Hope this helps to clarify it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the update after clarification:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(Recipient) %>% 
  mutate(Freq = paste(Recipient, ID),
         Freq = ifelse(Freq %in% Freq[duplicated(Freq)], "unique", "multiple"),
         Freq = ifelse(Recipient %in% Recipient[duplicated(Recipient)], Freq, "unique"))
```

```
  Recipient ID    Freq    
  <chr>     <chr> <chr>   
1 Smith     C     unique  
2 Wells     S     unique  
3 Wells     S     unique  
4 Jones     S     multiple
5 Jones     N     multiple
6 Wu        C     multiple
7 Wu        N     multiple
8 Wu        S     multiple
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I'm still having the issues with Recipients that occur more than once AND have the same ID for each recipient. These cases should be considered "Unique," but when I run this code these cases are returned as "Multiple."  Any other tips on how to solve this?

Comment: This is getting closer, but in the example above (Smith, C), (Wells, S)x2 should be classified as Unique, while (Jones, S), (Jones, N), (Wu, C), (Wu, N), (Wu, S) should be classified as Multiple.

Comment: Please see my update. Now it should work as desired.

Comment: Thanks TarJae, this code works like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution with `n_distinct()`:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(Recipient) %>%
  mutate(Freq = ifelse(n_distinct(ID) == 1, "unique", "multiple")) %>%
  ungroup()

# A tibble: 8 x 3
  Recipient ID    Freq
  <chr>     <chr> <chr>
1 Smith     C     unique
2 Wells     S     unique
3 Wells     S     unique
4 Jones     S     multiple
5 Jones     N     multiple
6 Wu        C     multiple
7 Wu        N     multiple
8 Wu        S     multiple
```

---

###### Data

```r
df <- structure(list(Recipient = c("Smith", "Wells", "Wells", "Jones", 
"Jones", "Wu", "Wu", "Wu"), ID = c("C", "S", "S", "S", "N", "C",
"N", "S")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```